# Problems when launching doveadm

Tags: email, dovecot, imap

I setup this weekend an new mail server to overtake the currently by ispconfig and dovecot managed accounts.

I have an issue when I run `doveadm`.

But first of all here's the config:

```
# 2.2.13: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian 8.1 
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_failure_delay = 1 secs
auth_verbose = yes
auth_verbose_passwords = yes
auth_worker_max_count = 20
disable_plaintext_auth = no
imap_metadata = yes
mail_attribute_dict = file:Maildir/dovecot-metadata
mail_debug = yes
mail_gid = 20000
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_plugins = acl imap_acl
mail_temp_dir = /home/mail/tmp
mail_uid = 20000
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date ihave
namespace {
  location = maildir:%%h/Maildir:INDEX=~/Maildir/shared/%%u
  prefix = Shared Folders/%%u/
  separator = /
  subscriptions = yes
  type = shared
}
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
  separator = /
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/master-users
  driver = passwd-file
  master = yes
  pass = yes
}
passdb {
  driver = shadow
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext
  driver = ldap
}
plugin {
  acl = vfile
  acl_shared_dict = file:/var/lib/dovecot/db/shared-mailboxes.db
  fts = lucene
  fts_lucene = whitespace_chars=@.
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
protocols = " imap lmtp sieve pop3"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = vmail
    user = vmail
  }
}
service dict {
  unix_listener dict {
    group = vmail
    mode = 0660
    user = vmail
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service lmtp {
  executable = lmtp
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
service managesieve-login {
  inet_listener sieve {
    address = 127.0.0.1 ::1
    port = 4190
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 110
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl = no
ssl_cert = /etc/ssl/server.crt
ssl_key = /etc/ssl/server.key
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext
  driver = ldap
}
verbose_ssl = yes
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = acl imap_acl sieve
}
protocol imap {
  mail_max_userip_connections = 20
  mail_plugins = acl imap_acl imap_acl
}
```

when I run `doveadm` I get following error message:

> doveadm(root): Error: dlopen(/usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib02_imap_acl_plugin.so) failed: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/lib02_imap_acl_plugin.so: undefined symbol: command_unregister
>
> doveadm(root): Fatal: Couldn't load required plugins

If you can tell me how I can reenable doveadm I would be very thankful.
I just don't see the issue where it is at

Comment: Are you sure you have to define `imap_acl` twice in the last block of config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have doubled `imap_acl` in the config, dovecot try to link that library twice

```
protocol imap {
  mail_max_userip_connections = 20
  mail_plugins = acl imap_acl imap_acl
}
```

Comment: this makes it easier. thx